# Too much nested class in my Swing class

Tags: java, swing, nested-class

I needed to use these nested class because nested class can use the variable from the class been nested. How do I move these class to a something.java to simplify my code and the class still have the control of the gui class , such as Jlabel?

this is the cleaned version to show the important part

```
public class GUI {

        public GUI(){

            VitaminDEngineStarter vdes = new VitaminDEngineStarter();
            Registry registry = null;
            try {
                registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
            } catch (RemoteException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                vd = (VitaminD)registry.lookup(VitaminD.SERVICE_NAME);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



            SMS a = new SMS(5);
            try {
                arduino.connect("COM3");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("connecting:"+ a.connect());
            System.out.println("connected? :" + a.checkConnect());
            System.out.println("signal: "+a.checkSignal());
            System.out.println("deliver report :" + a.DeliveryReportOn());
            SMS.Read read = a.new Read(arduino);


        }

        class ShowSense implements Runnable {


            @Override
            public void run() {
                String[] temp;
                String light = "";
                String temperature = "";
                String hum = "";
                String sens = "";
                boolean humanact = false;

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                while (true){
                    try {
                        humanact = vd.gethumanActivity();
                    } catch (RemoteException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    sens = arduino.getSensor();
                    temp = sens.split(",");
                    light = temp[1];
                    temperature = temp[0];
                    hum = temp[2];

                    LightIntensity.setText(light);
                    Temperature.setText(temperature);
                    humidity.setText(hum);


                    if (humanact){
                        personActivity.setText("in place");
                    }
                    else{
                        personActivity.setText("absent");
                    }

                }
            }

        }

        private JPanel getInputs() {
            if (Inputs == null) {
                personActivity = new JLabel();
                personActivity.setBounds(new Rectangle(114, 137, 77, 27));
                personActivity.setText("");
                personActivityLabel = new JLabel();
                personActivityLabel.setBounds(new Rectangle(7, 137, 99, 25));
                personActivityLabel.setText("Person Activity:");
                humidity = new JLabel();
                humidity.setBounds(new Rectangle(106, 91, 84, 27));
                humidity.setText("");
                humidityLabel = new JLabel();
                humidityLabel.setBounds(new Rectangle(6, 92, 88, 26));
                humidityLabel.setText("Humidity:");
                Temperature = new JLabel();
                Temperature.setBounds(new Rectangle(101, 50, 89, 30));
                Temperature.setText("");
                TemperatureLabel = new JLabel();
                TemperatureLabel.setBounds(new Rectangle(4, 50, 91, 30));
                TemperatureLabel.setText("Temperature:");
                LightIntensity = new JLabel();
                LightIntensity.setBounds(new Rectangle(110, 6, 84, 34));
                lightLabel = new JLabel();
                lightLabel.setBounds(new Rectangle(5, 5, 97, 34));
                lightLabel.setText("Light Intensity:");
                Inputs = new JPanel();
                Inputs.setLayout(null);
                Inputs.setBounds(new Rectangle(14, 63, 200, 183));
                Inputs.add(lightLabel, null);
                Inputs.add(LightIntensity, null);
                Inputs.add(TemperatureLabel, null);
                Inputs.add(Temperature, null);
                Inputs.add(humidityLabel, null);
                Inputs.add(humidity, null);
                Inputs.add(personActivityLabel, null);
                Inputs.add(personActivity, null);
                th.start();
            }
            return Inputs;
        }

        class autopilotthread implements Runnable{

            /** The temp. */
            private String[] temp;

            /** The lightintensty. */
            private double lightintensty ;

            /** The temperature. */
            private double temperature ;

            /** The hum. */
            private double hum ;

            /** The sens. */
            private String sens = null;

            /** The humanact. */
            private double humanact;

            /** The result. */
            private boolean [] result = {false , false};

            /** The fan. */
            private boolean fan =false;

            /** The light. */
            private boolean light = false;

            /** The pstop. */
            boolean pstop = false;

            /* (non-Javadoc)
             * @see java.lang.Runnable#run()
             */
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("thread start!");
                while(true){
                    System.out.println("thread loop!");
                        try {
                            if(vd.gethumanActivity()){
                                humanact = 250;
                            }else{
                                humanact = 0;
                            }
                        } catch (RemoteException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        sens = arduino.getSensor();
                        temp = sens.split(",");
                        lightintensty = Double.parseDouble(temp[1]);
                        temperature = Double.parseDouble(temp[0]);
                        hum = Double.parseDouble(temp[2]);
                        double [] out ={humanact ,lightintensty , hum, Time.now(),temperature };
                        System.out.println(""+out[0]+" "+out[1]+" "+out[2]+" "+out[3]+" "+out[4]);
                        result = Matlab.output(out);
                        light = result[1];
                        fan = result[0];
                        System.out.println("light:" + light);
                        System.out.println("fan:" + fan );
                        if(light){
                            try {X10.lightsOn();} 
                            catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

                        }else{
                            try {X10.lightsOff();} 
                            catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

                        }

                        if(fan){
                            try {X10.fanOn();} 
                            catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

                        }else{
                            try {X10.fanOff();} 
                            catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

                        }



                    try {TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);} 
                    catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

                    if (pstop){
                        break;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("thread stop!");

            }

        }

        class Pilotmouse implements MouseListener{

            /** The p thread. */
            autopilotthread pThread = null;

            /** The pt. */
            Thread pt = null; 

            /**
             * Instantiates a new pilotmouse.
             */
            Pilotmouse(){

            }

            /* (non-Javadoc)
             * @see java.awt.event.MouseListener#mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent)
             */
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            /* (non-Javadoc)
             * @see java.awt.event.MouseListener#mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent)
             */
            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            /* (non-Javadoc)
             * @see java.awt.event.MouseListener#mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent)
             */
            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            /* (non-Javadoc)
             * @see java.awt.event.MouseListener#mousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent)
             */
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            /* (non-Javadoc)
             * @see java.awt.event.MouseListener#mouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent)
             */
            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e) {
                if ((autopilotlable.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("off"))){
                    autopilotlable.setText("on");
                    pThread = new autopilotthread();
                    pt = new Thread(pThread); 
                    pt.start();

                } else if ((autopilotlable.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("on"))){
                    autopilotlable.setText("off");
                    pThread.pstop = true;
                }
            }

        }


        private JButton getAutopilot() {


            if (autopilot == null) {
                autopilot = new JButton();
                autopilot.setBounds(new Rectangle(18, 14, 112, 28));
                autopilot.setText("Auto Pilot");

                autopilot.addMouseListener(new Pilotmouse());
            }
            return autopilot;
        }


        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    GUI application = new GUI();
                    application.getJFrame().setVisible(true);
                }
            });

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jochen mentioned you could use Eclipse Refactoring Tools. That won't solve design issues though.

Generally:

- GUI knows about 14 classes and acts
  as big mediator... Is it possible to
  group logic into some    higher level
  classes and have GUI use them?
- Your code mixes object construction
  with logic. Try to move those actions
  to different places
- Don't start a thread inside
  constructor!
- Revise usage of logical
  statements. Eg. : 
   while(true){  ... if
         (pstop){    break; }}
- Is X10 3rd party class or your own?
  If it's yours try to remove global
  state(eg  use single instance of X10
  and instance variables for state
  change. Not static ones)

The most important advise: Please try to write unit tests for this functionality **first** using (for example) junit and mockito, and good design will come naturally. Believe me!

EDIT:

[Good talk about JMM](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1FX4zco0ziY)

[Good book about concurrency](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601).

EDIT:

[The Clean Code Talks - "Global State and Singletons"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FRm3VPhseI)

Comment: Thanks petro can i know why Don't start a thread inside constructor? i should start it in main? But the thread should stop after the GUI close ....

Comment: First of all I'm sorry. You are not starting thread inside constructor in your code. Since we already touched this topic here is article from Brian Goetz:  http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp0618.html

Comment: Hi , my program do have the problem stated in Listing 1. in the article from Brian Goetz , but how am i gonna solve it? using volatile? or use synchronized"?

Comment: If 'a = 1;' in Listing 1. was before thread.start then no race condition would occur because of 'happens-before' guarantee of thread.start. Your solution doesn't have this issue (please correct me if I am wrong). Also, since you are using 'synchronized' while reading/writing state you do not have visibility hazards (however I would use Read/Write lock instead of 'synchronized' in this case). I've updated answer with reference materials.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Eclipse's Refactor->Move Type to New File... to move some of the inner classes to their own file.